How to make hibernate to not track changes in certain EventListeners?
So, I am trying to create an encryption module for my Spring Boot application. The logic behind it is that I am registering some global event listeners to track each and every PreInsert, PostLoad, PostInsert event(s) (using Hibernate PostLoadEventListener interface etc). The requirements are:

On preInsert encrypt a given field
On postInsert decrypt a given field
On postLoad decrypt a given field

A sample code implementing the above flow is the following: (For simplification reasons I removed the code used to get/set the decrypted/encrypted value to the given object).
@Component
public class EncryptionEntityListener implements PostLoadEventListener, PreInsertEventListener, PostInsertEventListener {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EncryptionEntityListene2.class);

    @Autowired
    private EncryptionService encryptionService;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public void onPostLoad(PostLoadEvent event) {
        String decryptedValue = encryptionService.decryptData(...);
        //set decrypted value in object using setter of event.getEntity()
    }
    
    /**
     * Used after the first save of the object
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPreInsert(PreInsertEvent event) {
        String encryptedValue = encryptionService.encryptData(...);
        //set encrypted value to object by using event.getState()[field_index] = encryptedValue
        return false;
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onPostInsert(PostInsertEvent event) {
        String decryptedValue = encryptionService.decryptData(...);
        //set decrypted value in object using setter of event.getEntity()
    }

I am registering the event listeners in my configuration files and they are being called as expected.
The problem
After saving the object to database I want to decrypt it again and make it available inside the application. For this reason I implemented postInsert. Triggering the decryption in postInsert, postLoad event listeners make the changes being propagated to the database as well. Same applies when just asking (let's say with findById()) a certain object from DB, it's getting loaded in Hibernate session, decrypted by postLoad but the decrypted value is again being saved in DB :/
One more problem is that using preUpdate + postUpdate to catching the use case of an entity update, the postLoad event listener changes trigger the updateEventListener causing a ConcurrentModificationException because two(or more) listeners are making changes to the same object.
Things that I tried

Detaching (via event.getSession().detach(..)) the entity on postLoad before making any changes to the object. This has the wanted result, but throws "object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing" if further changes to the object are made by the application

Detaching the entity on postInsert doesn't have any effect at all. The entity is never getting detached and all the changes are being propagated to database

Flushing or clearing the session before making any decryption to entity fields doesn't work (and to my understanding it's strongly discouraged such practices in EventListeners)

Playing with .appendListeners() and prependListeners() on my configuration files where I register my listeners.

Using other functionalities such as @Converter annotation do not do the trick since I want to access the whole object when decrypting and not only a specific field.


Question
What am I missing here? How can I make hibernate ignore the changes I am doing to an entity and also don't break further changes being executed to the object? I start thinking that the approach of Hibernate Event Listeners maybe not be the proper solution for this use-case.

at first glance populating @Transient fields, and using them instead of jpa fields should help

Don't. Instead use a dedicated usertype for this and don't do this in event listeners as that will, as you noticed, change the object saving it etc. Instead use a dedicated usertype/convert. Why wouldn't the @Converter work, or rather what is the reason you would need the whole object?

The reason @Converter is not the case is that I am using a key rotation strategy. In this case, I need to extract the date this object was created (creationDate) and use that to pick the right key for decryption. Transient is also not the case as it would require changes to the entity to-be encrypted. I am trying to create a "plug-n-play" solution, that's why I want minimal code when importing this module in my projects
